# Responsive HTML not reacting as expected in different browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, responsive-design

So I am making a website but some weird thing is happening.

Like, you can see it happen by yourself, it's pretty staight forward; try opening this [link](https://www.artitrans.be/v1/artiTrans/index.php) into Chrome and Firefox (for example).

Chrome reacting just fine, and not Firefox.

As the two files are pretty long, I pasted those in pastebin:

- header.php (which is called in my index): http://pastebin.com/E7P9y7Dt
- style.css: http://pastebin.com/AxHQQJya

Can someone please help?

Thank you in advance.
Solid

Comment: Please try to mention specific issues you are facing in your code or approach next.

Comment: I think no one will read all the code you posted on pastebin, but all can look into the issue if mentioned, anyways i posted answer, take a look if it helps

Comment: You should add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This question will not help future visitors when that site has been fixed.

Comment: My bad; will try to make less mistakes next time when posting a question. Thanks for answering tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Css properties you are using works differently on different browser.

i checked the page found issue specific with logo css

use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: table-cell;`

finally your logo css should be

```
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 140px;
}
```

at line number 153

Comment: Thank you so much @Vikram. I don't actually know why I initially used table-cell... I used it in first instance because inline-block was causing me some problems but forgot to change it.

Can you also maybe guide me trough a solution with the resizing of the window? When you make the window less wider the logo resizes to full size for some reason. Could you help me here also? Thank you for your help.

Comment: check you media queries, you have set different css for different resolutions like `width:auto` and `display:block;` you need to change them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously vikrams solution worked. If you really need to display it as a table-cell for some reason, you can also solve it to declare properties inside the element like this.

```
<div class="logo">

    <a title="ArtiTrans" href="index.html">
        <img alt="ArtiTrans" src="images/logo.png" width="100%" height="100%"></img>
    </a>

</div>
```